# jQuery 2.1 trigger extraParameters not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventtrigger

Why not pass additional parameters, as it should be according to the documentation?

The same code works correctly jQuery 1.8

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="qqq">

$('input[value="qqq"]').on('click', function(event, data){
    alert(data);
});

$('input[value="qqq"]').trigger('click', ['QQQ']);
```

Example of working behaviour in jQuery 1.8: http://jsfiddle.net/kbr6h11z/1/

UPD1:
My solution to this problem:

```
$('input[value="qqq"]').on('click', function(event, data){
    alert(data);
    if (data!= null) $(this).prop('checked', !$(this).prop('checked'));
});

$('input[value="qqq"]').triggerHandler('click', ['QQQ']);
```

Comment: all work with `triggerHandler` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kbr6h11z/6/)

Comment: I need to change the state of input checkbox

Comment: so, where is problem?

Comment: "triggerHandler" - does not change the state of INPUT. Look here http://jsfiddle.net/kbr6h11z/7/

Comment: @Grundy OP has a point that the `trigger()` method is not working as documented. However, a question about why a particular version of jQuery potentially has a bug (or why the documentation is out of date) is probably not an on-topic question for SO.

Comment: interesting, seems that extraParams not passed if event is native, if event is custom - all work [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kbr6h11z/8/)

Comment: interesting observation. It would be nice to specify this in the documentation

Comment: The problem appeared from version jQuery 1.9

Answer (score 1):

You have to use 'change' event instead of 'click'.

```
$('input[value="qqq"]').on('change', function(event, data){
    alert(data);
});
$('input[value="qqq"]').trigger('change', ['QQQ']);
```

Comment: This worked. I don't know why, but it did... Not happy I had to change the event type though.